# the datasource for gridview Gridview1 didn't have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns. Ensure that your datasource has content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, gridview

This is the error I'm getting. The data is being retrieved through WebAPI, but due to a gridview setting, it is not displaying the retrieved data.

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44342/api/author");
              var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
              if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
              {
                  var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                  string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                  var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
                  //Console.WriteLine(arr);
                  GridView1.DataSource = arr;
                  GridView1.DataBind();
              }
              else
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
```

webform.aspx file gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Class="mygridview" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" BorderStyle="Solid" CellPadding="10"  >
                             <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="author_id" HeaderText="AuthorID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="author_name" HeaderText="firstName" />
                            </Columns>
                         </asp:GridView>
```

Controller code:

```
public IHttpActionResult getauthor()
        {
            librariaEntities lb = new librariaEntities();
            var results = lb.Authors.ToList();
            return Ok(results);
 
        }
```

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I took your advice and tried to deserialize the returned value, it worked eventually. This is the code that I used,

Comment: var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44342/api/author");
                var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    GridView1.DataSource = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Author>>(s);
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }

Comment: If my suggestions helped you, please consider marking my answer as your accepted answer. Thank you! (And congratulations on finding your solution!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this looks pretty simple.

The `GridView` control needs to bind to a list of objects. You're doing this with the `JArray`. So far, so good.

But the `GridView` doesn't know how to get properties called "author_id" and "author_name" from the objects in the `JArray`. There are no such strongly-typed properties in those objects.

Can you deserialize your return value from the web API as a list (or array) of `Author` objects?

Incidentally, you're working with ASP.Net WebForms, not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
        {
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44342/api/author");
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                GridView1.DataSource = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<Author>>(s);
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}", webResponse.StatusCode));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Deseriaziled the returned value from the web API as a list (or array) of Author objects and it worked eventually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).